# Bootstrap shows desktop navbar menu on 768

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a pag made with bootstrap. In customize i changed the @grid-float-breakpoint to md, and in my site the navbar being collapsed from 320 to 640, but 768px not!! in 768 it shows the collapsed menu but the content of this menu is the desktop version menu, look at this:

[image: It shows desktop navbar]

How I can fix it?

HTML CODE:

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-simelsa">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
       <div class="menu-text hidden-lg hidden-md">Menú<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed navbar-bottom" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-default">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-left" id="navbar-default">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav nav-simelsa-ul">
        <li class="inicio">
            <span class="border-left"></span>
            <span class="inicio-img"></span>
            <span class="border-right"></span>
            <a href="#">Inicio</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nosotros">
        <span class="nosotros-img"></span>
        <span class="border-right"></span>
        <a href="#">Nosotros</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown servicios">
        <span class="servicios-img"></span>
        <span class="border-right"></span>
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Servicios <span class="caret hidden-xs"></span><span  class="hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm">&#8594;</span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
       <li class="productos">
       <span class="productos-img"></span>
       <span class="border-right"></span>
       <a href="#">Productos</a>
       </li>
        <li class="noticias">
       <span class="noticias-img"></span>
       <span class="border-right"></span>
        <a href="#">Noticias</a>
        </li>
        <li class="contacto">
       <span class="contacto-img"></span>
        <a href="#">Contacto</a>
        </li>
     </ul>
     <div class="lang navbar-right nav navbar-nav"><span class="sp"><a href="#">ESP</a></span> | <span class="en"><a href="#">ENG</a></span></div> 
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

CSS CODE FROM MY STYLES:

```
@media (min-width: 1024px) {
.slick-prev, .slick-next {
    top: -12% !important;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 1024px) {

.header-bg {
    background: none !important;
}

.slick-prev, .slick-next {
  top: -13% !important;
  }
#navbar-simelsa a {
    font-size: 0.8em !important;

}

.slider-bottom {
  background-position: -35px -479px !important;
}
.box-content-carousel:hover .slider-bottom {
  background-position: -33px -499px !important;

}
}


.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li:hover{

}

.nav .open>a, .nav .open>li:focus, .nav .open>li:hover, .nav>li:focus, .nav>li:hover {
    color: #333;
  background-color: #dfdfdf !important; 

}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li:active{
  color: #333;
  background-color: transparent !important;
}
.navbar-nav>li>.dropdown-menu {
border-bottom: 2px solid #22a6cf;
}

.dropdown-menu>li>a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li {

    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease; /* Firefox */
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease; /* IE 9 */
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease; /* Opera */
    transition: all 0.3s ease;

}

.dropdown-menu>li>a:hover {
    color: #22a6cf !important;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {

 .navbar {
          margin-bottom: 0px !important;
    }
.footer-copyright {
    margin-left: 0px !important;
}
#navbar-simelsa a {
  font-size: 0.6em !important;
}
#navbar-simelsa ul.navbar-nav li {
  margin-right: 10px !important;
}
}
@media (max-width: 640px) {

.header-bg {
    height: 110px !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
    }
    .header-logo {

}

.social {
    margin-top: 10px !important;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

#layerslider .ls-s-1 {
height: 60px !important;
}
.footer-logo {
    padding-top: 30px;
}

.slider-bottom {
  background-position: -55px -479px !important;
}
.box-content-carousel:hover .slider-bottom {
  background-position: -53px -499px !important;

}

}

@media (max-width: 639px) {
    .header-bg {
    height: 95px !important;
}
.hide-640 {
    display: none;
}
.news-img img {
    width: 100%;
}
}
@media (min-width: 640px) {
    #layerslider-qs .ls-s-1 {
    background: #e3ebed;
    width: 200px;
    height: 357px !important;
    top: 0px !important;
    left: 0px !important;
    padding: 30px 30px 30px 35px;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif !important;
    font-weight: 200;
    line-height: 2em !important;
    color: #2c7081;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.1em !important;
}

.show-480 {
    display: none;
}
}
@media (max-width: 480px) {

      #layerslider-qs .ls-s-1 {
    background: #e3ebed;
    width: 110px;
    height: 357px !important;
    top: 0px !important;
    left: 0px !important;
    padding: 30px 30px 30px 35px;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif !important;
    font-weight: 200;
    line-height: 2em !important;
    color: #2c7081;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0.8em !important;
}
  .title-container-inicio {
      font-size: 1.3em !important;
  }
.footer-copyright  {

    font-size: 0.6em !important;

}

#layerslider .ls-s-1 {

    height: 40px !important;

}

.slider-bottom {
  background-position: -40px -479px !important;
}
.box-content-carousel:hover .slider-bottom {
  background-position: -43px -499px !important;

}


  .slick-prev, .slick-next {
  top: -13% !important;
  }

.box-content-carousel:hover .slider-bottom {
  background-position: -38px -499px !important;

} 

}
@media (max-width: 479px) {
.slider-bottom {
  background-position: 22px -479px !important;

    }
    .box-content-carousel:hover .slider-bottom {
  background-position: 24px -499px !important;

} 
.box-content-carousel img {
  margin-left: auto !important;
  margin-right: auto !important;
  }
    .slick-prev, .slick-next {
  top: -11% !important;
  }

  }

@media (max-width: 320px) {


.quienes-somos h1 {

    font-size: 1.5em !important;
}

.qs-links p {
    font-size: 1.1em !important;
}
      .header-bg {
    height: 90px !important;
}
    .slick-prev, .slick-next {
  top: -11% !important;
  }
  .box-content-carousel:hover .slider-bottom {
  background-position: -15px -499px !important;
}
.slider-bottom {
  background-position: -18px -479px !important;
}
  }

@media (min-width: 640px) and (max-width: 768px) {

.box-content-carousel h2 {
    font-size: 1.1em !important;
}
}

html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
        height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr=#dbeef4, endColorstr=#fff);
 background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #dbeef4 40%, #fff 50%);
 background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #dbeef4 40%, #fff 50%);
 background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #dbeef4 40%, #fff 50%);
 background-image:linear-gradient(top, #dbeef4 40%, #fff 50%);
 background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top, #dbeef4 40%, #fff 50%);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, right top, right bottom, color-stop(40%,#dbeef4), color-stop(50%,#fff));
   }

.nav .open>a, .nav .open>a:hover, .nav .open>a:focus {
    background: transparent !important;
}
.header-logo {
    background-color: #33add3;
    width: 100%;
 box-shadow: inset 0 -21px 19px -24px #808080;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 -21px 19px -24px #808080;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -21px 19px -24px #808080;
}
.header-bg {
   /* margin: 0 auto; */
     background-image:url('../images/header-img.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 500px 0;
    height: 133px;
}
.navbar-simelsa .lang a {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease; /* Firefox */
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease; /* IE 9 */
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease; /* Opera */
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif !important;
}
.sp a:hover {
    color: #c50000;
}

.en a:hover {
    color: #22a6cf;
}

.logo {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.nopadding {
   padding: 0 !important;
   margin: 0 !important;
}

.social ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 5px;

}

.social ul {
    list-style-type: none !important;
}

.social {
    margin-top: 73px;
}

/* Distorsiona el dropdown

#navbar-simelsa ul.navbar-nav li:first-child {
  border-left: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
  padding-left: 35px;

}
#navbar-simelsa ul.navbar-nav li {
  margin-right: 20px;
  border-right: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
  padding-left: 15px;
  height: 26px;
}

.dropdown-menu .divider {
  height: 1px;
  margin: -6px 0px 13px 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
}

.dropdown-menu li:first-child {
    padding-top: 10px;

}

#navbar-simelsa ul.navbar-nav li {
  margin-right: 20px;
  border-right: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
  padding-left: 15px;
  height: 26px;
}

#navbar-simelsa a {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif !important;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 0em;
    font-weight: 200;
    color: #464646;

}

*/

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif !important;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: 200;
    margin-left: 20px !important;
    color: #464646;   
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {

.navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a {
     font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif !important;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: 200;
    margin-left: 0px !important;
    color: #464646;   

}

}

@media (max-width: 1200px) {

.lang {
  border-right: 0px !important;
  border-left: 0px !important;
  line-height: 1.5em !important;
  margin-left: 20px !important;
  height: 29px !important;
  text-decoration: none;
} 

.navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a {
     font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif !important;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: 200;
    margin-left: 20px !important;
    color: #464646;   

}
}

#navbar-simelsa a:hover, #navbar-simelsa a:active, #navbar-simelsa a:focus {
        background-color: transparent;
}


@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .lang {
  border-right: 0px !important;
  border-left: 0px !important;
  line-height: 3.5em !important;
  margin-left: 20px !important;
  height: 49px !important;
  text-decoration: none;
}
    .contacto {
        border-right: 0px !important;
    }

     .nav-simelsa-ul>li:first-child a {

}

    .nav-simelsa-ul>li>a {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif !important;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    height: 49px !important;
    font-weight: 200;
    color: #464646;

}
    .navbar .navbar-nav {
        display: inline-block;
        float: none;
        vertical-align: top;
        height: 26px;

        }
    .navbar .navbar-collapse {
        text-align: center;
    }
.border-right {
  background: #dfdfdf;
  padding-left: 1px;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 9px;
  padding-bottom: 32px;
}
.border-left {
  background: #dfdfdf;
  padding-left: 1px;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 9px;
  padding-bottom: 32px;
}
    /* Para que funcione el cambio de color rollover
    .nav-simelsa-ul>li {

  padding-left: 10px !important;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  height: 26px;

}  
*/
.nav-simelsa-ul>li {
    height: 49px;
}
.nav-simelsa-ul>li.inicio {

    width: 113px;

}

.nav-simelsa-ul>li.nosotros {

    width: 130px;

}

.nav-simelsa-ul>li.servicios {

    width: 125px;

}

.nav-simelsa-ul>li.productos {

    width: 146px;

}

.nav-simelsa-ul>li.noticias {

    width: 125px;

}

.nav-simelsa-ul>li.contacto {

    width: 135px;

}

.servicios .caret {

    margin-bottom: 15px;

}
.navbar-simelsa {
        background: #f2f2f2;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    margin-bottom: 0px !important;
}
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
    background: transparent !important;
}



.menu-text {
      border: 1px solid #D2D2D2;
  height: 45px;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  color: #939393;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  padding: 10px 0px 10px 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.navbar-bottom {
    position: relative !important;
    margin-top: 0px !important;
    border: 0px !important;
    padding-top: 5px;
}

.navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  display: block;
  width: 22px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #939393;
  border-radius: 1px;
}


.inicio-img, .nosotros-img, .servicios-img, .productos-img, .noticias-img, .contacto-img {
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-top: 21px;
    margin-top: 14px;
    margin-left: 8px;
    float: left;
}

.inicio-img {
    background-position: 0px 0px;
}

.nosotros-img {
    background-position: 0px -28px;

    }

.servicios-img {
    background-position: 0 -59px;
}

.noticias-img {
    background-position: 4px -111px;
    padding-left: 25px !important;
    padding-top: 22px !important;
}

.contacto-img {
    background-position: 0 -138px;
}

.productos-img {
    background-position: 0 -84px;
}

.inicio-img, .nosotros-img, .productos-img, .noticias-img, .servicios-img, .contacto-img, .calendar, .slick-prev, .slick-next, .slider-bottom, .container-bottom-bg, .certified, .arrow-right {

      background-image:url('../images/sprites.png');
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.white-bg {
    background: #fff;
}
/* Breadcrumb */
.bc-simelsa>li+li:before {

    content: none !important;
}

.bc-simelsa>li+li:after {

content: "/ ";
padding-left: 4px;

}

.bc-simelsa>li+li:last-child:after {
content: none !important;
}
.bc-simelsa a {
    color: #818181;
    text-decoration: none;

}
.bc-simelsa {
    color: #818181;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif !important;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 1em !important;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #fff;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 0px !important;
    padding: 8px 10px;
}
.more-padding {
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
.arrow-right {
  padding: 11px 3px;
  background-position: 0 -626px;
}
.border-h1 {
    width: 170px;
    height: 1px;
    background: #cccccc;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    display: block;
}
.bc-simelsa>li+li:before {
    color: #818181;
    padding: 0 2px !important;
}
.two-border-hr {
    background: #fff;
    height: 2px;
    border-top: 1px solid #c6c6c6 !important;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c6c6c6 !important;
    margin-top: 0px !important;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-left: 5px;

}

/* Quiénes somos */

.quienes-somos h1 {
 font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif !important;
 font-weight: 500;
 font-size: 2.1em;
 margin-top: 10px;
 color: #83959b;

}

.quienes-somos p {
 font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif !important;
 font-weight: 300;
 line-height: 2.4em;
 font-size: 1em;
 margin-bottom: 25px;

 }

 .quienes-somos p.desc1 {

 color: #33add3;

 }
 .qs-links li {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
 }
 .qs-links a {
    text-decoration: none;

 }
.quienes-somos p.desc2 {

 color: #a3a3a3;
 margin-bottom: 30px;

 }
 .qs-links {
     list-style-type: none;
     padding-left: 0px;
 }
 .qs-links img {
     margin-right: 10px;
 }
 .qs-links p {
     font-size: 1.2em;
     color: #297b94;
     font-weight: 200 !important;
 }

.compartir {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-left: 15px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes swing
{
    15%
    {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(5px);
        transform: translateY(5px);
    }
    30%
    {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-5px);
       transform: translateY(-5px);
    } 
    50%
    {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(3px);
        transform: translateY(3px);
    }
    65%
    {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-3px);
        transform: translateY(-3px);
    }
    80%
    {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(2px);
        transform: translateY(2px);
    }
    100%
    {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
}
@keyframes swing
{
    15%
    {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(5px);
        transform: translateY(5px);
    }
    30%
    {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-5px);
        transform: translateY(-5px);
    }
    50%
    {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(3px);
        transform: translateY(3px);
    }
    65%
    {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-3px);
        transform: translateY(-3px);
    }
    80%
    {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(2px);
        transform: translateY(2px);
    }
    100%
    {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
}

.social ul li:hover
{
        -webkit-animation: swing 1s ease;
        animation: swing 1s ease;
        -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
        animation-iteration-count: 1;
}

/* LayerSlides */

#layerslider-qs {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#layerslider .ls-s-1 {
    background: #33add3;
    width: 284px;
    height: 260px;
    top: 45px !important;
    left: 60px !important;
    padding: 30px 20px 30px 35px;
}

#layerslider .ls-s-1 .title-box-slider {

    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif !important;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    font-size: 1.5em !important;

}

#layerslider .ls-s-1 p.desc {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif !important;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #1b1c21;
    line-height: 2em !important;
    font-size: 0.95em !important;

}    

.ls-container {
  margin-top: 2px !important;
  }

.hr-img {
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.welcome {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif !important;
    color: #999999;     
}
.welcome h1 {
    font-weight: 200;
    font-size: 2.1em;
}
.welcome p {
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    line-height: 1.7em;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.news {
    background: #e3ebed;
    min-height: 113px;
}

.news-img {
        overflow: hidden;

}
.news img, .news .box-text p {
      -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease; /* Firefox */
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease; /* IE 9 */
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease; /* Opera */
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.news:hover img {
      -webkit-transform:scale(1.25); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transform:scale(1.25); /* Firefox */
    -ms-transform:scale(1.25); /* IE 9 */
    -o-transform:scale(1.25); /* Opera */
     transform:scale(1.25);
}
.news:hover .box-text p {
    color: #707070;
}


.calendar {
    background-position: 0 -333px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    color: #33add3;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    font-weight: 300;    

}
.box-text {
    padding: 10px;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif !important;
}
.box-text p {
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #000;
}
.nopadding {
   padding: 0 !important;
   margin: 0 !important;
}

.title-container-inicio {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
    font-size: 1.6em;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif !important;
    color: #464646;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 0px !important;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}
.box-news {
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

/* Slider 2 */

.box-content-carousel {
    width: 268px;
    margin-right: 30px;
}
.slider-2 {
    margin-left: 15px;
}

.slick-prev.slick-disabled {
  background-position: 0 -416px !important;

}
.slick-next.slick-disabled {
  background-position: 0 -446px !important;

}
.slick-prev, .slick-next {
    width: 25px !important;
    height: 25px !important
}

.slick-next {
  right: 5px !important;
  background-position: 0 -356px !important;
}

.slick-prev {
  right: 35px !important;
  background-position: 0 -386px !important;
}

.box-content-carousel h2, .box-content-carousel p {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif !important;
  color: #838484;    
  font-weight: 200 !important;

}

.box-content-carousel h2 {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.slider-img {
    border: 3px solid transparent;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.box-content-carousel:hover .slider-img {
    border: 3px solid #33add3;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.box-content-carousel:hover {
    cursor: pointer;

}
.slider-bottom {
  background-position: 0 -479px;
  padding-top: 13px;
  display: block;
    -o-transition: all .5s;
  -moz-transition: all .5s;
   -webkit-transition: all .5s; 
  -ms-transition: all .5s;
}

.box-content-carousel:hover .slider-bottom {
  background-position: 2px -499px;

}

/* Footer */

.footer {
    background: #f5f6f6;
}

.container-bottom-bg {
  background-position: 73px -524px !important;
  padding-top: 20px;
  display: block;
  width: 738px;

}    

.footer-copyright {
    margin-left: 100px;
}

.footer-copyright, .footer-copyright a {
    color: #33add3;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif !important;
    font-weight: 500 !important;
    font-size: 1em;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-top: 15px;

}
.link-footer-col {
    max-width: 870px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;

}

.link-footer-col h4 a, .link-footer-col p a  {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif !important;
    font-weight: 300 !important;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    text-decoration: none !important;

}

.link-footer-col h4 a  {

    color: #33add3 !important;
    text-transform: uppercase;

}

.link-footer-col p a  {

    color: #464646 !important;
    font-size: 0.95em !important;
}

.link-footer-col p  {

    line-height: 0.9em;

}

.certified {
  background-position: 0px -530px !important;
  padding: 280px;
  display: block;
}

.certified-img {
    margin-top: 80px;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: i made you a jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/vhrahnct/. The error persists if you delete all the css, so that's not the error. The error shows from ~970px width to ~750px width, which translates to `-md` and `-sm`

Comment: i don't know (yet). i'm narrowing the cause down to what it is

Answer (score 0):

I have got it working:
http://jsfiddle.net/vhrahnct/1/

You still have to style your navbar, but the menu-thingy is displaying correctly now. I changed

```
<div class="menu-text hidden-lg hidden-md">Menú ...</div>
```

to

```
<div class="menu-text visible-xs-block">Menú ...</div>
```

Comment: Hi Flo, I changed "menu-text hidden-lg hidden-md" to "menu-text visible-xs-block" and the menu now dissapear in 768, it's not showing any menu... Thanks. If i add visible-sm-block, it shows, but shows the desktop menu version.

Comment: when do you want the menu to show? only xs and sm? are there different versions of the menu you want to show at xs and sm?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it.

I move:

```
.nav-simelsa-ul>li>a {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif !important;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    height: 49px !important;
    font-weight: 200;
    color: #464646;

}
.navbar .navbar-nav {
        display: inline-block;
        float: none;
        vertical-align: top;
        height: 26px;

}

.navbar .navbar-collapse {
        text-align: center;
}
```

From 768px min to 1024px min screen size.

Thanks!